# Find the minimum value of an expression.

Tags: inequality, optimization

Given that $x,y,z>0$ and $x\geq max${$y,z$}. Find the minimum value of:
$$A=\frac{x}{y}+2\sqrt{1+\frac{y}{z}}+3\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{z}{x}}.$$

This expression doesn't seem very "beautiful", I guess. And I have no idea what to do with this. What's your take on this?

Comment: One problem is with the term $y/z,$ which doesn't stay on a fixed side of $1.$

Answer (score 0):

First, we notice that $A(x,y,z)$ does not change if you multiply all arguments by the same positive number: $$A(\alpha\,x,\alpha\,y,\alpha\,z)=A(x,y,z)\quad\mbox{for any $\alpha>0$.}$$

Therefore we can impose a constraint $z=1$ without changing the answer and reduce the problem to that of finding the minimum of

$$A(x,y,1) = \frac{x}{y}+2\sqrt{1+y}+3\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{1}{x}}.$$

Now, taking partial derivative with respect to $x$, we get

$$\frac{\partial A(x,y,1)}{\partial x}=\frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{x^2}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{-\frac{2}{3}}$$

which is positive in the domain $x,y>0$, $x\ge \max(y,1)$.  Similar computation for $\frac{\partial A(x,y,1)}{\partial y}$ shows that it is negative in the same domain and therefore the minimum is achieved when $x$ is minimized to $x=1$ and $y$ is maximized to $y=x=1$:

$$\min A = A(1,1,1) = 1+2\sqrt{2}+3\sqrt[3]{2}.$$

Thanks Rob Pratt for pointing out the role of the domain.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But do you have any other way that doesn't use calculus?

Comment: This approach ignores the constraint $x \ge \max\{y,z\}$.  With the constraint, the optimal solution appears to be $(1,1,1)$, with objective value $1+2\sqrt{2}+3\sqrt[3]{2} \approx 7.608$.  Without the constraint, the optimal objective value appears to be $\approx 7.556$.